# Can SSIS generate PDF file for exporting data?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, ssis, msbi

I am moderately skilled with using SSIS. Know how to 
create a package and run. So far managed to save the 
output in flat files. now I need to advance to the next step.

Question: I need the query output to go to a PDF file.

Comment: https://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/generate-pdf-report-from-ssis/

Comment: @mohan111 hi , i dont wanted to use SSRS in this task. is there any other way to create a PDF using SSIS export ?

Comment: what ever the link I have given that one is related to SSIS

Comment: In the link u had given , it uses SSRS to generate PDF and that is linked with SSIS @mohan111

Answer (score 0):

No, SSIS cannot be used by itself to generate PDF files.

Not unless you have enough knowledge of the PDF format to write your own Script Task that will generate the file you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support in SSIS to generate PDF files. But you can create a task in SSIS package which can call a .NET assembly. See this post [http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1199/how-to-call-a-net-assembly-in-ssis] for step-by-step instruction of how to do it.

In your .NET assembly you will use a library which can create PDF documents, based on a MS Word template, formatted as needed with placeholders for data. In your .NET program you can then read any data .NET can read (database, xml, csv, json,…). This data is then merged into the final document, created from the template. This final document can be DOCX, PDF or XPS. These [examples](http://www.docentric.com/documentation/examples) show how this can be done.